# Server Side Events with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I want to listen for server side events and update accordingly using AFNetworking 3.0. I found info here [nshipster.com/afnetworking-2](http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/)

This is for AFNetworking 2.0.

This is what the code looks like for the 2.0 version,

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL];
[manager GET:@"/resources" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    [resources addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"resources"]];

    [manager SUBSCRIBE:@"/resources" usingBlock:^(NSArray *operations, NSError *error) {
        for (AFJSONPatchOperation *operation in operations) {
            switch (operation.type) {
                case AFJSONAddOperationType:
                    [resources addObject:operation.value];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    } error:nil];
} failure:nil];
```

The code above seems to be what I am looking for but with using AFN 3.0.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hey, if somebody is looking for simple package for SSE streaming in Swift client, you can use my new package https://github.com/RobertDresler/SwiftSSEStream

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly (that was a few years ago) support for Server-Sent Events was first moved from AFNetworking core to a separate library called AFRocketClient, and then was eventually abandoned.

Two possible solutions:

1. Although [the original AFRocketClient source repo](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFRocketClient) has been wiped, there is [a mirror here](https://github.com/usepropeller/AFRocketClient) which still contains the source. You could try to make that work with AFNetworking 3.
2. Alternatively, you could have a look at [EventSource](https://github.com/inaka/EventSource), an implementation of SSE in Swift.

I haven't seen too much usage of SSE in iOS apps. I think the Apple push notification service is a more popular approach for server-to-client notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am now thinking maybe I am a little confused and didn't explain what I am looking for correctly. I want to listen for event changes to the json like key "1" = value "a" and if the value changes server side to key "1" = value "b" then my data will change app side and update accordingly.

Comment: Yes, if your server supports Server-Sent Events than you can use one of the solutions I provided.

Comment: I will, give these a try and come back with the results. Thanks